# Can banner ads and interstitial ads still be displayed even without Google Play Services installed?

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads

I'm using

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.*
```

in my main activity.

In my *build.gradle*, I have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

under *dependencies*.

If I run the app on an emulator (Genymotion, Nexus 4, 4.1.1) without Google Play Services installed, the ads are still displayed. When I implement a check functionality for Google Play Services as described [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/google-play-services-setup.html), the app correctly detects that Google Play services aren't installed.

Does it mean, that ads created with `com.google.android.gms.ads...` still work on devices without Google Play Services installed?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary. For many reasons you cannot compare an emulator to an actual device as it is linked with the Android SDK and IDE. The same behaviour may/may not be observed on an actual device.

However , since Google says that generally each update of Google play Services reaches a large percentage of devices regularly(as it is not restricted by carrier or OEMs), **I'd recommend always checking for Google play services before showing ads to avoid any crash.**(If a user doesn't have latest GPServices, the only loss is that he will not be shown ads , however a crash may cause him to leave a bad rating which could've easily been avoided.)

Useful related resource : http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html